# Count the number of results in a seperated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know I could probably just count the commas but I wanted to know if theres a built in way to count the results in a comma seperated list?

**e.g**

```
DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(100)
SET @IDS = '2,3,54,234,'

SELECT
  COUNT(value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IDs)) AS [Count]
FROM
  Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @IDs NVARCHAR(100)
SET @IDS = '2,3,54,234,'

SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    STRING_SPLIT(@IDs, ',')
```

Comment: This is great however it still returns 1 if the string is empty ''. Any idea how to mitigate this?

Comment: You can add contition `WHERE value <>  ''`